# How can I stop Google from crawling my website?

Tags: development-process

I have incorporated google analytic code into my website, however, I don't want Google to crawl through my website for some days. If I run "robot.txt", still my website can be viewed in google search result page. I don't want it to be shown at all for the specified period of time? 
How can I stop google from crawling my website? Also, how can I set the duration?

Comment: Offtopic for SQA please ask on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is related to Web page management.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set below code in robot.txt ( you need to stop googlebot looking at your website )

- User-Agent: googlebot
- Disallow: /

Its not happen in one day, Its take some time when google next time crawling your website then it not access your website.

Comment: In addition you can provide Google an XML sitemap of pages you want scrapped using their Web Master portal. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183669?hl=en